# okta + rest api + java swing redirect exception how do you retrieve url data

Tags: java, swing, okta, rest

I am trying to integrate OKTA security with a Java Swing application using a Rest API Call.

I understand how to make the call properly and how to make REST calls.

In Java Swing, I do not want to use any kind of browswer.  The REST call to OKTA redirects the authentication call returning the auth code.  However, at the same time, this is throwing a HttpClientErrorException.

I know if I paste my authentication call in a browser, I see the 404 error, however, the code is also in the URL returned which I need.

When I inspect both the exception and my rest api object in java, I don't the full redirect url so I can't access that code.

Has anyone else done this and have any ideas?

Comment: Here's a JavaFX tutorial that might help: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/08/14/javafx-tutorial-oauth2-oidc

Comment: Yes, I've seen the JavaFX thanks.  However, we are not using the JavaFX SDK, we are just a java swing application implementing this.  I was hoping somebody found a different way besides going to JavaFX SDK.